# Select2 in edit form not triggering the selected values in edit form- Livewires

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, livewires

I have a select2 in a livewire component. Everything works fine but in my edit view, the selected options dont show in the box as selected. When I open the dropdown they show as highlighted, so data is coming from backend.

```
 <div  wire:ignore class="col-8">
                                        <select wire:model="notificationType" class="form-control select2 text-sm"
                                                multiple="multiple">
                                            @foreach($notificationTypeOptions as $key => $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $option }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

     $('.select2').select2({
                width: '100%',
                tags: true,
                multiple: "multiple",
            });

            $('.select2').on('change', function (e) {
                var data = $('.select2').val();
            @this.set('notificationType', data);
            });
```

Please If someone could help...

Answer (score 0):

use seperate ids for your select boxes and call select2 by id

```js
$('#edit-select').select2()
$('#create-select').select2()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use this code inside the blade components:

```
@if (in_array($key, $notificationType)) {{'selected'}} @endif
```

Everything As-It-Is only changes in select option tag: like below code:

```
<option value="{{$key}}" @if (in_array($key, $notificationType)) {{'selected'}} @endif>{{ $option }}</option>
```